# How to send heredoc command to background?

Tags: shell, background-process, here-document

I want to send a heredoc command like this one

```
cat <<EOF
line 1
line 2
EOF
```

to background. (The actual command is `openssl` with many lines of input which takes some time to complete).

The command needs to be storable in string so that I could `exec` it in PHP.

Simply appending an ampersand doesn't work:

```
cat <<EOF
line 1
line 2
EOF &
```

Any other combinations I tried (putting the command in brackets etc.) don't work either.

How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The here-doc operator (`<<EOF`, here) is just a regular redirection operator, and what comes after it (on the same line!) is still part of the command.

E.g.

```
# from here-doc to file
cat <<EOF > foo.txt
...
EOF

# here-doc and some arguments to cat
cat <<EOF -n foo.txt
...
EOF

# two here-docs!
cat /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 3<<EOF 4<<EOF
first
EOF
second
EOF
```

So you'd do the same as if it was just a redirection from a file, put the `&` at the end of the `cat` command line:

```
cat <<EOF &
here-doc text
EOF
```

Comment:   You can even do things like `cmd1 << EOF | cmd2 3<< EOF2 &`

Comment: Or `if grep -q word <<EOF; then` with the here-doc data next, and the rest of the compound command coming after it.